# remove blank and whitespaces from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I get rid of whitespaces and blank items in an array

```
names = ["alice", "", "bob", " ", "yankee"]
```

desired result should be

```
["alice", "bob", "yankee"]
```

Comment: I think you've made a mistake with your *should get* array.

Comment: ok, re phrased it, I don't think it's a dup question, all I found was to use `.reject` which doesn't reject spaces and blank items in an array, Ursus answer helped me a lot!

Comment: Look at the elements in your second array, they are not from the first array.

Comment: "Marked as a duplicate" except this is tagged ruby-on-rails and ruby, and the duplicate is marked just ruby, which gives other answers. E.g. in rails I would prefer using `blank?` and `present?` while in the duplicate they (obviously) prefer `empty?` which is only available on strings (but is pure ruby).

Comment: How did this question get upvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In rails is simple, use `present?`

```
names.select(&:present?)
```

Comment: thanks you. that is what I was looking for, helped lot!

Comment: My pleasure Sir

Comment: also works for ruby

Comment: `present?` is a rails' method though

Answer (score 0):

If you try this below it will provide you with a new array assigned to newNames that does not include the empty elements.

```
newNames = names.reject { |n| n.empty? }
```

Comment: No, it doesn't, ` " "` is not empty. You need to write `p names.reject{|str| str.strip.empty?}`